# Base Class vs Common Member Class

Tags: design, design-patterns, inheritance, composition

Imagine I have two classes like this...

```
public class SingleplayerGameSetup
{
    public int Seed { get; private set; }
    public int AiNations { get; private set; }
}

public class MultiplayerGameSetup
{
    public int Seed { get; private set; }
    public int AiNations { get; private set; }
    public List<IpAdress> Clients { get; private set; }
}
```

...and I really don't like the fact that they have common members.

When I take the base class approach, the `SingleplayerGameSetup` class becomes empty:

```
public abstract class GameSetup
{
    public int Seed { get; private set; }
    public int AiNations { get; private set; }
}

public class SingleplayerGameSetup : GameSetup
{
    //This class is basically empty right now.
}

public class MultiplayerGameSetup : GameSetup
{
    public List<IpAdress> Clients { get; private set; }
}
```

The other way that I can think of is to create a class that holds the common members:

```
public class SharedGameSetupSettings
{
    public int Seed { get; private set; }
    public int AiNations { get; private set; }
}

public class SingleplayerGameSetup
{
    public SharedSettings SharedGameSetupSettings { get; set; }
}

public class MultiplayerGameSetup
{
    public SharedSettings SharedGameSetupSettings { get; set; }
    public List<IpAdress> Clients { get; private set; }
}
```

Which approach is better? Or, is there a better approach?
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "better?"  **Note:** don't answer this question with a tautology, like "best practice."  *State your specific requirements.*

Comment: @RobertHarvey If I have known what should I look for, I could figure this out by myself. So you tell me, what should be my requirements?

Comment: I personally prefer the base class approach in this instance, but there's also the "favor convention over configuration crowd," so pick your poison.

Comment: @RobertHarvey "Convention over configuration" or "Composition over inheritance" ?

Comment: @Spotted: Shhh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's call your first option option A, and the second one option B.

Your only peeve about option A is that `SingleplayerGameSetup` *"is basically empty right now."*.

I think that doesn't matter because obviously your code will grow with time and chances are `SingleplayerGameSetup` will not be empty forever. You cannot foresee the future.

In option B, you would need to either write wrapping methods for every `SharedGameSetupSettings` (which will be a rather long list of settings I'm guessing), or access shared settings one way and non-shared settings in a different way.

I think for the point of view of the client code all settings should be accessed in the same way.

**Although I'm usually inclined to favor composition rather that inheritance, in this case I would go with option A.**

Answer (score 2):

Second option makes more sense from an encapsulation and class responsibility standpoint. In fact the word "Shared" is not really required - Settings captures a Seed and AiNations (whatever these might be) for any Game Setups.

I wouldn't recommend creating abstract classes just to enable code re-use, unless the abstract class/interface really defines the signature of what it and all the implementations represent. In fact in the above example, in addition to introducing the Settings class, one could also define an interface that defines the signature that all GameSetup implementations need a way to define the Settings - i.e. a new interface called GameSetup that has a getSettings() method, that both SinglePlayerGameSetup and MultiPlayerGameSetup implement - because I would imagine you can't have a GameSetup without defining a Settings for it.

Comment: Implementing an interface makes perfect sense. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

There really is no difference from what you have now and the second option you stated. Once again, you have common members, only they are now encapsulated in one class. This mitigates the problem when you need to add or change something in SharedGameSetupSettings, but if you need to add something else that is common for both SingleplayerGameSetup and MultiplayerGameSetup and it is not related to SharedGameSetupSettings, you have the same problem as before.

Therefore, you are left with the first option. The alternative can be to not make the SinglePlayerGameSetup an abstract class. If this is the entire scope of your problem, then this approach is the best, in my opinion. You have everything you need there and your solution is not overdesigned.

However, as @Tulains Córdova said, it is highly unlikely that these classes will not grow, which makes the first design a logical choice.

Comment: No, that's not the entire scope. I simplified my code to keep question simple and short. So I can't really use SingleplayerGameSetup as a base class of other.